# Remove points from vector depending on distance between pairs of points

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a vector of `cv::Point` points that are x,y coordinates. I'd like to remove points if they are too close to each other e.g < 20. I have trouble writing the lambda function correctly.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> points(5);
points[0] = cv::Point(150, -700); // some random values
points[0] = cv::Point(146, -710);
points[0] = cv::Point(600, -500);
points[0] = cv::Point(140, -500);
points[0] = cv::Point(150, -550);

points.erase(std::remove_if(points.begin(), points.end(),
    [](cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2)
    {
        return sqrt(pow(pt2.x-pt1.x,2)+pow(pt2.y-pt1.y,2));
    }), points.end());
```

The problem is in the parameters of the lambda function. If I specify two cv::Point arguments as shown above, then there are compilation errors. If I just specify one argument as in `(cv::Point pt1)` then it compiles fine but then I can't access the second point.

How would I go about solving this?

Edit:

1. Sorry for the lack of information. Here's more details:
   If `v = [a b c d e]` where the elements are 2d points consisting of x,y coordinate values and b and c are very close to each other then I want to remove c like so: `v = [a b d e]`
2. I get the vector from a different process over which I have no control so I can't verify the distance and prevent its insertion into the vector

Comment: It needs to return a bool like `return sqrt(pow(pt2.x-pt1.x,2)+pow(pt2.y-pt1.y,2)) < 20;`

Comment: You need to be more accurate: say points _A_ and _B_ verify _d(A,B)_ < 20, do you remove them both? If no, which one would you keep? And how does this generalize to _N_ points verifying the criteria

Comment: what is the compilation error?

Comment: Btw, `points[0] = cv::Point(150, -700);`, `points[0] = cv::Point(146, -710);`, etc You just put them all to the start so only the last one will be left

Comment: remove_if is essentially a loop which processes one element of the input range at a time. You'll need something more complex than a standard algorithm to solve your problem.

Comment: 'std::remove_if' works with UnaryPredicate, receiving one Point at a time, you can't use it to find all pairs answering certain condition.

Comment: The problem isn't well defined: if two points are close to a third one, which one of them should get removed?

Comment: @DimChtz I said it, to illustrate that the problem is ill-defined.

Comment: *I'd like to remove points if they are too close to each other* -- What made the points close to each other to begin with?  Is it just that you're adding points to the vector before checking the distance, or is it that the points were not too close, but their x,y values changed over the course of the application?  If it's the former, then the solution is simple -- don't add the point to the vector.

Comment: sorry if my question was vague. If points p1 and p2 are close, I want to remove p2. 
@OhadEytan There's a whole lot of error messages that it takes forever to scroll them. That's why I did not include them

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I'm getting the vector from another thread which I cannot modify.

Comment: @DimChtz, the values I put are completely random. Please ignore the values. I just know there are some points very close to one another. I see them when I plot them.

Comment: @user1420 And if `p2` is close to `p3`, should you also remove `p3`, or should you leave it in because `p2` gets removed? See what I mean?

Comment: OT, you can avoid the square root and compare the square of the distance with 400.

Comment: @juanchopanza I did not think of that. After removing p2, the distance from from p1 to p3 should be considered to decide to retain or reject p3.

Comment: @Bob, thanks for the idea. Will use that.

Comment: Say close to each other means less than 20. If `v = [0 100 15 200 30]` result is `[0 100 200 30]`, but if `v = [15 100 0 200 30]` the result is `[15 100 200]`?

Comment: @arekolek, No quite. I have a vector of coordinates. If the distance between pairs of points are less than 20, then the second point should be removed. In my edit, v = [a b c d e]  a,b...e refer to 2D points but you just take the difference of scalars.

Comment: Whether the points are in 1D, 2D or 3D doesn't matter. You are missing the point of my question. My example is in 1D for simplicity, try to answer it as it is.

Comment: I will translate my question into 2D for you: If `v = [(0,0) (0,100) (0,15) (0,200) (0,30)]` the result is `[(0,0) (0,100) (0,200) (0,30)]`, but if `v = [(0,15) (0,100) (0,0) (0,200) (0,30)]` the result is `[(0,15) (0,100) (0,200)]`?

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out the flaw in Humam's answer, here is another way to do it:

```
unsigned nb_removed = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - nb_removed; ++i) {
    for (auto j = i + 1; j < points.size() - nb_removed; ++j) {
        if (cv::norm(points[i] - points[j]) < 20) {
            std::iter_swap(points.begin() + i, points.end() - nb_removed - 1));
            std::iter_swap(points.begin() + j, points.end() - nb_removed - 2));
            nb_removed += 2;
            --i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
points.erase(points.end() -nb_removed, points.end());
```

Note that this will remove points which are close to each other two by two. So if for instance, you have *p1, p2, p3* such that *d(p1, p2) < 20* and *d(p2, p3)* < 20, then *p1* and *p2* will get removed but *p3* will remain untouched. If this is the behavior you want then a simple loop like the one above cannot solve this. I would suggest more elaborate data structures like [*KD-trees*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to deal with that sort of situation

Comment: I would like to remove single point at a time. If d(p1,p2) < 20, remove p2. Next if d(d1,p3) < 20, remove p3. I will try and see if I can adapt your answer to this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted Rerito's answer;
You want to remove one of the points that are close to each other less than a given threshold distance, and let's say you want to remove the smaller valued element from the vector.   You can use the following code;

```
unsigned nb_removed = 0;
int threshold_distance = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < V.size() - nb_removed; ++i) {
    for (auto j = i + 1; j < V.size() - nb_removed; ++j) {

        if (abs(V[i] - V[j]) < threshold_distance) {

            if (V[i] < V[j]){
                std::iter_swap(V.begin() + i, V.end() - nb_removed - 1);
                nb_removed += 1;
                --i;
                break;
            }else{
                std::iter_swap(V.begin() + j, V.end() - nb_removed - 1);
                nb_removed += 1;
                --j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
V.erase(V.end() -nb_removed, V.end());
cout << "after process: \n";
for (int i=0; i<V.size(); i++)
 cout<< V[i] << " - ";
cout << endl;
```

An example output is given below.

Before process vector elemets:

```
1 - 11 - 33 - 30 - 10 - 2 - 112 - 111 - 199 - 211
```

After process vector elements:

```
211 - 11 - 33 - 112 - 199 - 2
```